Do PCs with an RS232 port use that port to display POST/BOOT/startup information?
I am troubleshooting a Dell Precision 7920 Tower. It does not boot, however it is not your typical PC problem like standard no boot, no post, no video or no power.
It turns on, seems like it does POST because it does not return any POST codes, BUT it shows no disk activity, spamming F12 does not show UEFI settings, ethernet seems to negotiate with router and no DELL logo is shown at any time. Motherboard seems to be able to at least read UEFI settings as the fans spin to the desired offset value I have configured them with.
Given the apparent complicated problem I want to know if listening to the serial port with another device would show up POST info like a journalctl log but for the POST process.
I have already tried to turn on with the minimal hardware like single RAM stick and no HDD, but nothing changes.
I am asking because I don't have a USB to serial cable, and where I live hardware in general is expensive.

If you have a voltmeter (e,g, DMM) then you could try to check for voltage fluctuations on the TxD pin referenced to ground. Of course checking with an oscilloscope would be better in detecting any serial output. But the probability of any output is IMO likely zero (i.e. you'll measure a steady negative voltage, the Mark level).

It turns on, seems like it does POST because it does not return any POST codes, but does not show video output. In fact, it shows no disk activity, no POST codes, nothing - most of the things I ate for breakfast did the same, except the "it turns on" part. Is there something suggesting that it's not the power switch alone that works?

I'm not sure I understand how "it is not your typical PC problem like standard no boot, no post, no video or no power" but "does not show video output. In fact, it shows no disk activity, no POST codes, nothing". What does it actually do that makes you think it's on? Are there any fans running? Any LEDs turning on? Does it react to toggling Caps Lock? Are USB devices powered? Is there any video output? Which version of the 7920 is it (tower or rack...)? If it has multiple video outputs, have you checked all of them? Does the Ethernet port light up, or even better, blink?

@tevemadar Switch from Kellog's cereals to Post cereals to get POST codes from your breakfast :-) (Actually, maybe you do eat Post cereals - you said "most", not "all")

@tevemadar I don't get the parallels between troubleshooting a pc and eating breakfast. Is that IT lingo for something specific?

@jcaron Sorry, language barrier. English is not my native language so apologies. What I wanted to say was that it was a not your typical (as shown here )"No Video" problem because those tend to assume your system did POST and did BOOT, its just that you can't actually interact with the PC's IO properly because you need the screen to do that. Yes USB devices are powered, but caps lock don't work. Ethernet does seem to negotiate with network devices, as activity lights do work.

It was a joke related to the post describing a number of things that the PC in question does not do, and not doing PC things doesn't even require a PC. Your most recent comment describes things that are happening, I'd suggest writing them in the question. The bad news is that power getting to places like the USB controller or the network card doesn't mean much, they're quite autonomous pieces of hardware. While Caps/Num locks not working still suggest the motherboard has some nontrivial hardware failure.

@tevemadar Describing what a PC isn't doing is actually a standard troubleshooting approach - it helps narrow down the problem. When a PC stops doing "PC things," it indicates a malfunction. Your breakfast comparison doesn't really work since we're specifically discussing computer diagnostics in a computer forum. I have adjusted the post to include further details. At the time I didn't think to include details about the problems because the question title was not asking about help with troubleshooting but rather find alt means of doing so. My bad though, I already added additional details.

In general not. Most modern computers don't have serial ports anymore and those that have, usually don't have this capability.
It is mostly a servers and workstation feature and almost always you need to enable it (in the Bios of UEFI configuration) first before it is usable.
As it happens this Dell 7920 system still has a serial port, but you will need to check the manual to see if serial console is available on it or not.
I took a look at the user-manual and the UEFI config settings allow you to set the serial port as COM1 to COM4 and to disable it altogether.
But there is no setting to use it as serial console.
So you are out of luck.

The original IBM PC (the basis for x86 "modern [personal] computers") did not have a serial console because a serial port was an optional adapter card. The required user interface was a video monitor and keyboard. Serial ports were commonly integrated on a PC motherboard only after semiconductor integration improved to the level of SuperI/O chips

Much like the serial port, the floppy drive (and card) was optional. The original PC booted to Basic and had a builtin port on the back where a cassette tape recorder could be connected for storage.

Thanks a lot, I did also consulted the DELL manual, but was hoping I was missing something. I figured because usually other computer based systems do have simple SPI interfaces that automatically display bootup processes (like some fridge, micros) and the serial port was pretty conspicuous since I seriously doubt anyone was using it  as a vanilla shell interface you'd configure a whole server with.

Most computers - there are always exceptions - have one and only one default boot console.
For the IBM PC and compatible market - from 8088 on up to i9 and beyond - that has pretty much always been a memory mapped video controller detected by the BIOS. Originally that was CGA or MDA, and many later video systems initially presented to the system as compatible to CGA or MDA (primary differences from the perspective of the BIOS generating text was simply the memory address and I/O address ranges).
For a while - from the first microcomputer systems in the early 1970s up through sometime probably in the late 1980s, there were plenty of competing systems. Many of them - e.g., Apple ][, TRS-80, Atari, Amiga, etc. - had their own default memory-mapped video schemes that were considered to always be active on startup. For many others, particularly CP/M systems, the default would be either the serial port or the first serial port (of many, perhaps dozens!) in the system. And for some systems there was no true boot console at all, just a bunch of diagnostic lights (if you were lucky), with no boot console until after at least part of an operating system was loaded via a floppy drive.
The one notable, and much more recent, exception is using a network connection. An example of this is HP's Integrated Lights Out (ILO). This is typically found on servers and not on ordinary workstations, at least not in my general experience.
In fact, in a system that always (or nearly always) includes a video output that functions as the boot console, you don't want to have the boot information echoed on the serial port. Why? Because that serial port would often be connected to a printer. Leave your checks or other special forms in the printer and then every time you boot up you would lose a page to the boot messages, which would not be a very good thing. In addition, if the serial port is not configured via good old-fashioned dip switches then the default BIOS configuration (e.g., 9600,n,8,1) might not match the actual device configuration set during operating system startup, in which case instead of seeing a printed boot message you would see gibberish or nothing at all.
(Minis and mainframes were likely similar, but I don't have any hands-on experience or extensive knowledge to really compare, so I started with the microcomputer era.)

"from the first systems in the early 1970s ..." - FYI computer systems existed long before "the early 1970s".

Back in the early 80's, I used an CP/M Intertec Super Brain which had a memory mapped video controller. We edited files using WordStar. We would connect a modem to the serial port (1200 bps) and run the "modem7" program to connect over the phone lines to a Cyber mainframe. IFAIK, the Cyber could only be accessed using video terminals or printers with keyboards. We would then run our Fortran programs on a Cray-1, which could only be accessed by having the Cyber submit batch jobs.

In other words, the Cray-1 had no human interface. The point is that back then the faster the computer, the crapper the human interface. Later, when the Cray-2 arrived, we could connect from Sun Sparc Unix boxes via X windows. That Cray-1 was moved to the lobby and used as furniture.

The big exception for quite a few years now has been IPMI, but that is usually only available on server-grade machines, and the Dell Precision 7920 does not support it.
